# How would I make my Linux machine seem like it's running Windows?

Tags: linux, windows

I need my Linux system to look like it's running Windows to any websites that want access my operating system data. Is something like this possible without the use of a VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Firefox addon called "Modify Headers", using this you could use the Header of what a Windows machine would send.

More info [here](https://invisiblecomputer.wonderhowto.com/how-to/trick-websites-into-thinking-youre-different-os-browser-0141843/)